# Getter method is returning 0 value

Tags: java

I'm creating a class MDA_EFSM and it has two variable int k and int[] listA and creating setter and getter methods to initialize these two variables. Then I'm calling getter method of MDA_EFSM in another class. The getter method should return recently set value, but it is returning '0'.

```
public class MDA_EFSM {
    int k;
    public int listA[] = {0, 1};   

    public int getK() {
        return k;
    }
    public void setK(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }

    public int[] getA() {
        return listA;
    }
}

public class State {
    MDA_EFSM mda = new MDA_EFSM();

    public void setMda(MDA_EFSM mdaefsm)
    {
        mda = mdaefsm;
    }
    public MDA_EFSM getMda() {
        return mda;
    }
}

public class S0 extends State{

    public void Insert_cups(int n){
        if (n > 0){
            int value = mda.getK();
        }
    }
}
```

I am setting value in one class and getting that value from another class. Here is the code snippet of that class:

```
public class S1 extends State{
    public void Insert(int n){
        if (n > 0){
            mda.setK(n);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of recently set value, but getter method is returning '0'

Comment: Where on your code `setK` is called?

Comment: *"The getter method should return recently set value"* You never call `setK` so there is no "recently set value".

Comment: Actually I'm setting value in one class and getting that value from another class. Here is the code snippet of that class:` public class S1 extends State{ public void Insert(int n){ if (n > 0){ mda.setK(n); } } }`

Comment: @Pie I have modified the question now. I have added the code where I'm setting the  K

Answer (score 1):

You haven’t set any value.  You got default value of int.  By the way I cannot see in code you set any value for int.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I'm setting value in one class and getting that value from another class. Here is the code snippet of that class:                         
 public class S1 extends State{
 public void Insert(int n){
  if (n > 0){
   mda.setK(n);
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Each of your class S0 and S1 has an own instance of MDA_EFSM (by the way you should read Java naming convention). You set the Value of k in S1 but read the value of another k in S0. To achieve what you want k hast to bee static.